# Initializing a variable-length c-string in a class

Tags: c++, optimization

Say I have a class **Uniform** like so:

```
class Uniform {
public:
    Uniform(const char* name, size_t count, size_t elemSize, void* data);

private:
    size_t m_count;
    size_t m_elemSize;
    void* m_data;
    char m_name[];
}
```

Is there a way to initialize *m_name* such that the data contained is tightly packed? I'd rather not have to have either use a high-water mark on the string (Such as *char m_name[MAX_STR_LEN];*) or dynamically allocate it.

Comment: Not a struct, it is a class.

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[flexible arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) is C99 feature. Use `std::string`, or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, or `char *m_name = new char[...`

OR

use templates

```
template <size_t size>
class Uniform {
public:
    Uniform(const char* name, size_t count, size_t elemSize, void* data);

private:
    size_t m_count;
    size_t m_elemSize;
    void* m_data;
    std::array<char, size> m_name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you declare it as char* m_name; after the first assign it will take the efficient size.
and you can change this in future too by

```
char * m_name = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));//size_t count is the n
```

Comment: I think the poster intends for the class to own the C string.

Answer (score 1):

You need dynamic allocation for dynamic things.  Suppose you had:

```
Uniform array[10];
```

or:

```
std::vector<Uniform> v;
```

How do you expect indexing to work if each `Uniform` has a variable size? `Uniform` must have a fixed size known at compilation time.